# Same variable in outer and inner function of closure

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
var a=10;
function Print(){
    var a=20;
    return function(b){
        var a=30;
        return a*b;
    }
}

console.log(Print()(5)); //output 150
```

Here I want to access the Print variable which is var a=20; or global variable which is var a=10;

is there any way to do this without changing the variable name.

Comment: By giving the variables different names.

Comment: Using _var_ means that the variable _a_ has a function scope, and if it is defined at top of all is global. So you are just reassign values to the same variable despite you're continuing using _var_. Instead you should declare other variables with _let_ that has a block scope. If you cannot use _let_ for compatibility, than you just have to change the names.

Comment: is there any way to do this without changing the variable name.